# How to return an enumerated type in a PHP SOAP Server

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I am building a web service using php core SOAP classes, and need to return a variable of enumerated type. This is the type definition in WSDL:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="ErrorCodeEnum">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
          <xsd:enumeration value="OK"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="INTERNAL_ERROR"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="TOO_MANY_REQUESTS"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

server.php:

```
<?php
class testclass {
   public function testfunc($param) {
      $resp = new testResp();
      $resp->errorCode = 'OK'; #SoapServer returns xsd:string type.
      return $resp;
   }
}

class testReq {}

class testResp {
   public $errorCode;
}

$class_map = array('testReq' => 'testReq', 'testResp' => 'testResp');
$server = new SoapServer (null, array('uri' => 'http://test-uri/', 'classmap' => $class_map));
$server->setClass ("testclass");
$server->handle();
?>
```

Answer:

```
<ns1:testResponse>
     <return xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct">
        <errorCode xsi:type="xsd:string">OK</errorCode>
     </return>
</ns1:testResponse>
```

How can i do to return type `ErrorCodeEnum` instead of `string`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. There was some problem about server not loading the WSDL file. This is the `types` section in the WSDL:

```
<wsdl:types>
   <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://schema.example.com">
      <xsd:simpleType name="ErrorCodeEnum">
         <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="OK"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="INTERNAL_ERROR"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="TOO_MANY_REQUESTS"/>
         </xsd:restriction>
      </xsd:simpleType>
      <xsd:complexType name="testResp">
         <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element name="errorCode" type="xsd:ErrorCodeEnum"/>
         </xsd:all>
      </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

Actual server answer:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://schema.example.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:testResponse>
         <testReturn xsi:type="ns1:testResp">
            <errorCode xsi:type="xsd:ErrorCodeEnum">OK</errorCode>
         </testReturn>
      </ns1:testResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it out:

[Calling web service (SOAP) with PHP involving enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829809/calling-web-service-soap-with-php-involving-enums)

Enumeration only specifies allowable values. As long as you're passing back a string which evaluates as "OK", "INTERNAL_ERROR", or "TOO_MANY_REQUESTS", then it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, but It's not the same problem. Since i'm building a server, not a client, i must return the right type.